# Had vs Have had

Tags: grammar, tenses, present-perfect, simple-past

I was wondering if the following phrases

1. I had no idea you were there
2. I've had no idea you were there

are both grammatically correct? As a rule, I've seen the 1st option much more often than the second one, but I'm not quite sure whether this is the case of a more common usage or there is some grammar behind it.

Comment: (2) isn't ungrammatical (you could say _Since January I have had no communication from you_), but it doesn't feel like a natural thing to say. I can't exactly explain why.

Comment: @KateBunting so it's more about the usage and not really about the grammar?

Comment: Can you give an example of the circumstances in which you imagine someone saying it?